# python if statement not filtering out the cases

Tags: python, if-statement, text

So I have a dictionary of character and their nickname.

```
namedict = {"Harry Potter": ["Harry","Harry Potter"]}
```

I would like to write a function to detect if the name appear in the sentence and if exist, what would be the emotional status of the character.

```
import text2emotion as te

def emotion(character, text):
    with open(text,'r') as f:
        for name, nickname in namedict.items():
            if character in name:
                print(str(character)+"\n")
                line = 1
                for lines in f:  
                    if (alias in lines for alias in nickname):
                        print("line "+str(line))
                        print(te.get_emotion(line))
                        line += 1
            else:
                print("character not found")
```

while when I run the code with my text file, it just returns every line, and apparently it is not taking characters not exist in the name list from the loop.

[text sample and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyYgy.png)

Comment: It's a simple course group project so we will ignore if the emotion data comes out is from the character or not.

Comment: Where are `l` and `te` defined? Are they global variables?

Comment: `if character in name` is not right.  What is `character` supposed to be here?  Are you searching for a single character?  If so, then you don't need the `for` statement at all, just `if character in namedict:`, but nothing in here is looking at `text`.  What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: You are opening the file once, then `enumerate()`ing it multiple times.  Every time after the first will yield zero lines, because the file position will be at the end of the file - there's nothing more to read beyond that point.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `'print debuging'`

Answer (score 0):

When file read all lines - `for lines in f:` - then it stops at the end and it has nothing to read. It doesn't know that you want to read all lines again. But you try to read all lines again for next name.

I see three solutions:

**First:**

You have to inform file that you want to read from the beginning -  `f.seek(0)`
(eventually you could close file and open it again but it waste of time)

```
      for name, nickname in namedict.items():           
          # ... code ...

          f.seek()   # move to beginning of file to read lines again

          for lines in f:  
              # ... code...
```

**Second:**

First read all lines to list in memory

```
      all_lines = f.readlines()

      for name, nickname in namedict.items():           
          # ... code ...

          for lines in all_lines:  
              # ... code...
```

**Third:**

You have to change order of `for`-loops to read all lines only once

```
      for lines in f:  
          # ... code... 

          for name, nickname in namedict.items():           
               # ... code ...
```